# Java Scanner - How can i check if the password is entered correctly?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I wanted to check if the password was entered correctly with Scanner in Java.

I tried with this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please enter your username:");
        Scanner username = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello " + username.nextLine() + ", please authenticate using your password:");
        Scanner password = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pw = "test";
        String pwEnter = password.nextLine();
        if (pw != pwEnter) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, you don't have access to the System.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Thank you for authenticating, you can proceed with:");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

`if (pw != pwEnter) {`

to

`if (! pw.equals(pwEnter) ) {`

Take a look at this question:  [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)